# Formatting elements of a list python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi I have this function that maps and joins the elements of a list into a string. My question is that is there was a way to add quotation marks around all the elements that are originally strings in the list.

```
  def blahblahblah(input):

     code  = "result = %s\n" % (", ".join(map(str, input)))
     print code




  x = ["dasdad", 131]
  blahblahblah(x)

  //normal output ------result = dasdad, 131 
 //desired output ------result = 'dasdad', 131
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Padraic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36585178/2069350) has already answered your stated question quite well, so I won't duplicate his work here. Instead, I'm taking a leap and attempting to answer your question in a more general form.

---

It *looks* like you're trying to recreate Python literals in your formatted output. For objects like strings and numbers, the built-in [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) function will do this for you.

```
>>> def blahblahblah(input):
...     code  = "result = %s\n" % (", ".join(map(repr, input)))  # Map repr instead of str
...     print code
... 
>>> blahblahblah(["dasdad", 131])
result = 'dasdad', 131
```

`repr` is one of the most versatile Python builtins for exploring and debugging, and its utility certainly isn't limited to string formatting. If you're not familiar with it already, I strongly suggest you become so!

Answer (score 2):

You can map `str.format` wrapping each element in whatever you want:

```
def blahblahblah(inp):
     code  = "result = {}\n".format(", ".join(map("'{}'".format, inp)))
     print code
```

So each element in your list will be wrapped in quotes in your output:

```
In [2]: x = ['dasdad', 131]

In [3]: blahblahblah(x)
result = 'dasdad', '131'
```

Or for just the str types, use *isinstance*:

```
def blahblahblah(inp):
     code  = "result = {}\n".format(", ".join(['"{}"'.format(s) if isinstance( s, str) else str(s) for s in inp)])
     print code
```

Which gives you:

```
In [5]: x = ["dasdad", 131]

In [6]: blahblahblah(x)
result = 'dasdad', 131
```

Comment: This will put quotes around every element of the list. He only wants around the first AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

you can add quotation mark to string first.

```
x = [ "\"" + i +"\"" if isinstance(i,str) else i for i in x]
code  = "result = %s\n" % (", ".join(map(str, x)))
print code
```

result = "dasdad", 131

```
print "result = %s\n" % (", ".join(map(str,  ["\"" + i +"\"" if isinstance(i,str) else i for i in x])))
```

Comment: You need change 'input' to 'x' in the first example.